# Reinforcement Learning, understanding off-policy methods

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I read the paper of [DDPG](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02971.pdf)

> Many approaches in reinforcement learning make use of the recursive
>   relationship known as the Bellman equation:
>   $$
>   Q^{\pi}(s_t, a_t) = \mathbb{E}_{r_t, s_{t+1} \sim E} \left[ r(s_t, a_t) +
>     \gamma \mathbb{E}_{a_{t + 1} \sim \pi} \left[
>       Q^{\pi}(s_{t+1}, a_{t + 1}) \right]  \right]
> $$
>   If the target policy is deterministic we can describe it as a function
>   $\mu: \mathcal{S} \leftarrow \mathcal{A}$ and avoid the inner expectation:
>   $$
>   Q^{\mu}(s_t, a_t) = \mathbb{E}_{r_t, s_{t+1} \sim E} \left [ r(s_t, a_t) +
>     \gamma
>       Q^{\mu}(s_{t+1}, \mu(s_{t + 1})) \right]
> $$
>   The expectation depends only on the environment.
>   This means that it is possible to learn $Q^{\mu}$ off-policy, using
>   transitions which are generated from a different stochastic
>   behavior policy $\beta$.

And I don't understand why **The expectation depends only on the environment** causes **This means that it is possible to learn $Q^{\mu}$ off-policy, using
transitions which are generated from a different stochastic
behavior policy $\beta$**?